# Cannot plot this small dataset after transpose

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, dataset

[image]
This is my data set after i transpose it.
When I try to plot this dataset I get different type of errors based off of the codes I use:
when using

```
df.plot("Country Name", "China")
```

I get KeyError: 'Country Name'

```
df.plot.line()
```

Gives KeyError: ('Country Name', 'China')

```
x = dfg1_2_4.iloc[:,0]
y = dfg1_2_4.iloc[:,1]
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

gives 'single positional indexer is out-of-bounds'.

anyway to plot line this dataset or fix any of these errors?

I think i need to remove the first line of the data set but

```
df = df.reindex(df.index.drop(0))
```

is not working

Comment: Could you copy-paste the output of `print(df)` into your question?  It's far easier to debug with at least the text of your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df = df.reindex(df.index.drop('Country Name'))
```

then

```
df.plot()
```